# Django_tables2: CSS isn't working even though it's registered

Tags: python, html, css, django

I copied the screen.css that has the paleblue class shown in the example on the django_tables2 website.

I placed it in my application in the static/css folder and when I call it from my .html it finds it. In the header I placed the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/screen.css" />
```

Now, in my tables.py module I have this:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
class TipPredmetaTable(tables.Table):
class Meta:
    model = models.TipPredmeta
    attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

In my views.py I have this:

```
def tippredmeta(request):
    queryset = TipPredmeta.objects.all()
    table = TipPredmetaTable(queryset)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render_to_response('azuriranje/tabela.html', {"table": table}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I open the page in Mozzila and hit Ctrl+U I can clearly see the following:

```
<div class="table-container"><table class="paleblue"><thead>&#32;<tr>...
```

My .html is exactly the same as on the django_tables2 website, my STATIC_URL is defined, the staticfiles app is enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the source, does the link still say `href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/screen.css"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out after some more extensive searching through the web and my code. It would seem that me forgetting to put `'django.core.context_processors.static'` in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` was the source of my issue.